# Plotting results of NIntegrate with variable integration limit

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I have tried to use `NIntegrate` with variable limits and compute the following

```
(*parameters*)
Ωm = 1.0;
ΩΛ = 0.0;
Ωk = 
  1 - Ωm - ΩΛ;

(*Integral with variable limits*)
 A[a_?NumericQ] := (5 Ωm)/
       2 ((Ωm a^-3 + ΩΛ + \
    Ωk a^-2)^(1/2)) NIntegrate[
        1/(x (Ωm x^-3 + ΩΛ + \
    Ωk x^-2)^(1/2))^3, {x, 10^-7, a}];

   (*plotting data giving values to `a`*)
  Plot2 = ListLinePlot[A[a], {a, 0.1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

I supposed that `A[a]` was "free" until `ListLinePlot` give values to `a`, but no.

**Another problem is that NIntegrate is not working here, the plot at the end looks like y=x.**

Comment: Only related tangentially, but these kinds of cosmological integrals always caused me annoyances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You only missed to create the list that you want to plot. Here are your definitions:

```
  (*parameters*)
Ωm = 1.0;
ΩΛ = 0.0;
Ωk = 
  1 - Ωm - ΩΛ;

(*Integral with variable limits*)
A[a_?NumericQ] := (5 Ωm)/
    2 ((Ωm a^-3 + ΩΛ + \
Ωk a^-2)^(1/2)) NIntegrate[
    1/(x (Ωm x^-3 + ΩΛ + \
Ωk x^-2)^(1/2))^3, {x, 10^-7, a}];
```

Here is the list with the structure `{a, int}`:

```
  lst = Table[{a, A[a]}, {a, 0.1, 1, 0.05}]
```

and then one should plot the list, rather than the function:

```
 Plot2 = ListLinePlot[lst, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

which returns the image below:

[image]

You could also do it as follows skipping the list stage:

```
Plot[A[a], {a, 0.1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

The returned image is identical to the one above.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. But the plot looks like y=x, right? I suppose the problem is inside the integration.

Comment: OK,  new problem. NIntegrate is not integrating, it only evaluates the limit "a" and makes the table.

Comment: That's because your integral *is equal to `a`*.

Comment: Solved problem.